# How to add a filename to multiple text files which are tab separated at 7 column

Tags: bash

I want to add the filename at 7 column for multiple tab separated text file
My file looks right now like this:

```
chr1    467293640   .   G   A   35.3963 PASS    AF
```

I want output like this

```
chr1    467293640   .   G   A   35.3963 s372-937    AF
```

Right now i am using a code like this

```
awk -vOFS='\t' '{$7 = "s372-937"; print}'
```

for a single file but how can i perform for multiple files

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Which shell are you using? Does each file have only one line? Is `s372-937` the name of the file you are writing to, or is it the name of some other file? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1438911/edit) and add these information.

Comment: You can access the current filename in awk using the `FILENAME` built-in variable - see for example [The GNU Awk User's Guide: 7.5.2 Built-in Variables That Convey Information](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Auto_002dset)

Comment: Is that _really_ your file or is this a VCF file that also contains headers starting with `#` that need to be excluded? Also, what is the file name? Can we just use the actual name of each file as steeldriver explains above? Finally, if this _is_ a VCF file, adding the file name will break it and programs that expect VCF won't be able to handle it.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver it worked by using the FILENAME built-in variable.